# JGiven localize intro word

Tags: java, bdd, jgiven

I'm working on a project where the domain is defined in french. I'm using JGiven to write tests and I'm trying to get the report completely in french. I'm using the Spring Test infrastructure by inheriting `SpringScenarioTest` in my test classes.

Here's an example of what I did:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfig.class)
public class TrainDateTest extends SpringScenarioTest<GivenTrainDate, WhenTrainDate, ThenTrainDate> {

    @Test
    @As("Création d'un train date")
    public void creation_d_un_train_date() {
        given().un_train_date();
        when().je_lance_la_creation_du_train_date();
        then().le_train_date_resultant_doit_avoir_un_id_en_base();
    }
}
```

I found out how to translate intro word like `and()` or `with()` using the `@IntroWord` annotation in my `Stage` classes, but how can I translate the `given()`, `when()` and `then()` intro words?

The problem seems to be that these intro words are defined by the `Scenario` class which is created by the `ScenarioTestBase` class and I can't find a way to override this behavior without rewriting the entire class hierarchy.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can have a look at the `com.tngtech.jgiven.lang.de.SzenarioTestBasis` which provides this for German already. Just create a subclass of `SpringScenarioTest` and define the methods that you need as follows:

```
public class FrenchSpringScenarioTest<ETANTDONNE, QUAND, ALORS> extends
    SpringScenarioTest<ETANTDONNE, QUAND, ALORS> {

    public ETANTDONNE etant_donne() {
         return getScenario().given( "etant donné" );
    } 

    public QUAND quand() {
         return getScenario().when( "quand" );
    } 

    public ALORS alors() {
         return getScenario().then( "alors" );
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly fine, thank you!